# Ошибка Cannot resolve symbol 'FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY'

Tags: java, android

Приложение должно менять цвет всех букв l на красный, но есть одна единственная ошибка Cannot resolve symbol 'FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY'.

```
package com.example.myapplication;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Html;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    private Button _ok_button;
    private EditText input_TextBox;
    private TextView output_TextView;
    

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        _ok_button=(Button) findViewById(R.id.okButton);
        output_TextView= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.outputTextview);
        input_TextBox=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputTextview);

        _ok_button.setOnClickListener(this);
       }
         public void onClick(View v) {
            if (v.getId()==_ok_button.getId()){
        String text=input_TextBox.getText().toString();
        String Text = text.replaceAll("(l)", "<font color='red'>$1</font>");
        output_TextView.setText(HtmlCompat.fromHtml(Text, HtmlCompat.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY), TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);  //ругается на FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY в этой строке
    }
```

Есть HtmlCompat.java, в нем

```
package com.example.myapplication;


import android.text.Html;
import android.text.Spanned;

public class HtmlCompat {

    public static Spanned fromHtml(String source) {
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
            return Html.fromHtml(source, Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY);
        } else {
            //noinspection deprecation
            return Html.fromHtml(source);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Удалите свой класс `HtmlCompat` - он дублирует библиотечный, либо используйте **его** метод (он у вас с одним параметром вообще-то)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это плохая практика называть и использовать вместе в коде классы так же как и в используемых библиотеках.

Вы используете `HtmlCompat.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY`, который обьявлен тут
https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/text/HtmlCompat

никак не в вашем `HtmlCompat`, который импортируется по умолчанию.

Переименуйте ваш `HtmlCompat` в скажем `MyHtmlCompat` и дальше AS вам все подскажет.